# Slim 3 redirect route loop not working

Tags: php, routes, slim

I'm trying to make a simple route to redirect endpoints to a specific URL based on an array/key.

```
$redirects = [
    "/ios" => $GLOBALS['config']['iosAppStoreLink'],
    "/android" => $GLOBALS['config']['androidAppStoreLink']
];

/**
 * Redirects
 */
foreach($redirects as $endpoint => $url) {
    $app->get($endpoint, function($request, $response) {
        return $response->withRedirect($url);
    });
}
```

The endpoints get created without issue just once I'm inside of the `$app->get` function, it will not allow me to use `$url`... I get an `Undefined Index` error in my console.

What am I doing wrong here, why am I not able to access the `$url` variable?

Comment: `function($request, $response)` knows __noting__ about `$url` variable.

Comment: @u_mulder How can I pass it into that function? Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow the function to access the `$url` from outside of it's own scope, you could use `function() use() {` syntax...

```
foreach($redirects as $endpoint => $url) {
    $app->get($endpoint, function($request, $response) use ($url) {
        return $response->withRedirect($url);
    });
}
```